# How to build an eclipse plugin with sbt and sbt-osgi?

Tags: eclipse, scala, plugins, sbt

Is it possible to build an eclipse plugin with a sbt build ?

Once built, do I just drop de jar in the plugin directory of eclipse ?

Update:

- [sbt-tycho](https://github.com/ashewring/sbt-tycho) look promising but for sbt 0.7

Comment: sbt-tycho looks like dead.  No activity in 3 years!!!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [giter8](http://github.com/n8han/giter8) template from the scala-ide group to build a scala eclipse plugin using maven

`g8 scala-ide/scala-plugin.g8`

Update:

Best way to create a plugin is via the plugin developpement environement (PDE). From there you can add the scala nature.